# RestFB: Get good resolution image from a post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I need good resolution pictures from "photo" type posts. The general "[user_id]/feed" api endpoint gives you a "picture" field with bad resolution. The good resolution ones come in a field called "images" that doesn't seem to be included in that endpoint. I can only get them when calling with [post_id] directly. E.g.: http://graph.facebook.com/10151901949756749

I'm noticing the Post class in com.restfb.types doesn't have an "images" attribute so it doesn't seem like "fetchObject([post_id], Post.class)" would work.

How can I get these images?

Comment: Do you have a sample Post call that you're trying to get the image from?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? As mentioned, I'm trying to get the image on call like this: 
http://graph.facebook.com/10151901949756749
And it's a GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In facebook API, we get the pictures with different dimensions, as different sizes of the same images are saved. But some basic conventions can be helpful to identify the resolution of images:

1. `_s.png` or `_s.jpg` , this represents small image.
2. `_n.png` or `_n.jpg` , this represents normal image.

So for example when you call : http://graph.facebook.com/10151901949756749

You get a sub part  something like this:

```
   {
   "picture":"...._s.png",
   "source": ".._n.png",
   }
```

Here, instead of fetching `picture` you can retrieve `source` , and the image you will get will be of better resolution.

Comment: Only now I've noticed this "source" field comes with the "detailed post" endpoint as well. RestFB can get it (while it can't get "images") so it solves my problem.

To make the "detailed post" bit clear:
example of detailed post: "http://graph.facebook.com/10151901949756749" (where that number is the post's "object_id")
example of non detailed posts: "http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed" (add your token with "read_stream" permission)